# How to check tag is img or video in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to open image / video in modal popup so I have a button on click I can show image. but when I have both image and video its difficult that how can I check that tags in jQuery.

My html code for zoom image in popup

```
<div>
    <img src="image/zoom-icon.png" id="zoomImg" >
    <div class="bigthumb">
        <img src="image/main_product_img.png" id="myImg" width="350px" height="350px">
        <video class="no-display" width="350px" height="350px" controls>
           <source src="image/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">              
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <img src="" class="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;" >
        <video class="videopreview no-display" class="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;" controls>
            <source src="" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery_file code is here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#zoomImg').on('click', function() {
        console.log($(this));
        if ( ---HERE-- ) {
            $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $('.bigthumb').find('img').attr('src'));
            $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
        } else {
            $('.videopreview source').attr('src', $('.bigthumb').find('video source').attr('src'));
            $('.videopreview').show();
            $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
        }
    });     
</script>
```

on above script i want to check in if condition that is img tage / video tage

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments

```
if($(this).is('img')){
  //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `nodeName` property to check the element type:

```
$(this).prop("nodeName")
```

Or:

```
this.nodeName
```

The values would be `IMG` or `VIDEO`.

> The Node.nodeName read-only property returns the name of the current node as a string.
>
> Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can use its is() method, or you can use plain JS:

```
$('#zoomImg').on('click', function (evt) {
  switch (evt.currentTarget.tagName) {
    case 'IMG':
      // logic here
      break
    case 'VIDEO':
      // logic here
      break
    default:
      console.warn('Unsupported zoom target')
  }
})
```

PS: Mainly, this is slightly faster as calling .is() method, as there is no additional code executed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `nodeName` to do this

```
if(this.nodeName == 'IMG')
```